# Pandas. Быстрый поиск уникальных строк

Tags: python, pandas

Доброго времени суток.

ЗАДАЧА: найти в датафрейме pandas строки, которые повторяются лишь один раз.

ПРИМЕР: в таблице 2 столбца, по строкам - `(1,2)` `(1,3)` `(1,2)`. Запись `(1,3)` встретилась 1 раз, она нам и нужна (её индекс в датафрейме).

ВОПРОС: как это сделать самым быстрым способом?

было решение «в лоб»: пробегаюсь по фрейму, считая количество встречаемых уникальных записей, если 1 - то это то, что мне нужно

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Покажите, какие были попытки?

Comment: @АлексейР было решение «в лоб»: пробегаюсь по фрейму, считая количество встречаемых уникальных записей, если 1 - то это то, что мне нужно

Comment: Код можете показать?

Comment: @АлексейР знаю, что такая задача решается быстро xor

Comment: @АлексейР df_slice - фрейм frequency = dict()
            for k in range(df_slice.shape[0]):
                t = df_slice.iloc[k].name
                key = tuple(df_slice.iloc[k].values)
                if key in frequency:
                    frequency[key][1] += 1
                else:
                    frequency[key] = [t, 1]

Comment: Сколько записей во фрейме?

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy 30-35 тысяч

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy проблема в том, что это надо делать по всевозможным выборкам из столбцов, т.е. срезам. В таблице 9 столбцов, из 9 по 3 уже немало

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно удалить дубликаты, останутся только уникальные записи. Забрать индексы

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2],[1,3],[1,2]])
print(*df.drop_duplicates(keep=False).index) # 1
```

Comment: В чем именно путаница? Уникальный - [единственный в своём роде, неповторимый, существующий в одном экземпляре](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9)

Comment: Извиняюсь, проверил, все как мне надо. Не знал про параметр keep. Спасибо!

Comment: Очень круто! Я выучил новый прием.